# Binance Crypto Exchange API Error -1131 recvWindow must be less than 60000

Tags: api, binance

I have a problem with my PHP script which was working before without problem. I dont know whay it have stop to work, because i dont have change anythink.

I am getting the error message:

> array(2) { ["code"]=> int(-1131) ["msg"]=> string(37) "'recvWindow' must be less than 60000." }

So i did think ok easy i will just make the setting "recvWindow" smaller then "60000", but then the next error message comes also somethink with "recvWindow"

> array(2) { ["code"]=> int(-1021) ["msg"]=> string(56) "Timestamp for this request is outside of the recvWindow." }

So what is wrong what must i do to make it work again? Here is the complete script which i have:

```
        <?php
        //--API Call
        $nonce=time();
        //--
        $url='recvWindow=10000000000000000&timestamp='.$nonce;
        //--
        $sign=hash_hmac('SHA256',$url,$apisecret);
        $url=$url.'&signature='.$sign;
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-MBX-APIKEY:'.$apikey));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account?".$url);
        $execResult = curl_exec($ch);
        $Balances = json_decode($execResult, true);
        var_dump($Balances);
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i did slove the problem, if you write the nonce parameter in milliseconds instead of seconds, then it works, and try to change the recwindow value also if you still get difficulties:

> $nonce=round(microtime(true) * 1000); //time();